# MouseEvent doesn't exist

Tags: flash, click, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I can't seem to get my MouseEvent to work. I get the 1120: Access of undefined property MouseEvent error. I'm sure it's something simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

import gameLib.Layer;
import gameLib.Audio;
import gameLib.GameSprite;

public class Game extends MovieClip {

    public function Game() {
        OM.game = this;

        Audio.init();
        Layer.init(stage);

        OM.buyButton = new BuyButton(stage);
        Layer.world.addChild(OM.buyButton);
        OM.buyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OM.buyButton.onClick);
```

I have other code I'm following. The code that I'm following is not written in OOP style is written in a Procedural manner so I'm assuming it's something to do with that. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: What is this `BuyButton' class? Is it something you wrote or something from a library you are using?

Comment: You need an import: `import flash.events.MouseEvent;`

Comment: Yeah that was it. I needed to import. It's weird I don't have it in my other code and that one works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import MouseEvent:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```

[Import](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000183.html) should be required, but I have also noticed some flakiness especially within Flash Professional.

> The import statement applies only to the current script (frame or
>   object) in which it's called. If an imported class is not used in a
>   script, the class is not included in the resulting SWF file's
>   bytecode, and the class isn't available to any SWF files that the FLA
>   file containing the import statement might load.

Often I'll quickly scan code for a warning symbol on the line or underlined syntax highlight; then, engage content assist <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to generate the import.

If you're using Flash Builder, the organize imports statements command is handy:

Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>